# Debugging WP7 Silverlight Layout

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Does anyone know if is there a tool inspect the control hierarchy in Silverlight, similar to a DOM browser in HTML?  I am trying to give my app the same look and feel in light and dark themes, and I'm having troubling isolating the phone resource that is causing a few elements to still change color.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also endorse [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/blog/silverlight-spy-4/) for this sort of thing. With it you can drill down through the visual tree, examine properties of UI elements, and with the paid version you can change those properties on the fly to see the results. If you combine that with Reflector (or one of the clones floating around) you have everything you need to extract and test styles.

Note that there is (now) a free version of Silverlight Spy but it is quite hobbled, if your budget allows you may as well just grab the full version (it is one of those tools you will use frequently, so well worth it).

Answer (score 0):

Google SilverlighSpy application. It does that plus more

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains have made [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) available. It is currently free (hope it stays that way, unlike .Net Reflector).

It will also convert Silverlight DLLs all the way back to readable source code! I have tried it on several SL projects and it works like a charm.

**Note: as of the time of this writing it still gets a couple of things wrong: string concatenations and event handlers generate the wrong code.*